# java.util.regex.Matcher.replaceAll replacing without a match?

Tags: java, regex

According to the javadoc:

Replaces every subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern with the given replacement string.

This seems to indicate that this call will not replace, unless a match is made.

And yet:

```
public class MisMatch {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Pattern doubleSlash = Pattern.compile("\\\\");
        String stringWithSingleSlash = "maybe\\no";
        System.out.println("Matches:"+doubleSlash.matcher(stringWithSingleSlash).matches());
        String replace = doubleSlash.matcher(stringWithSingleSlash).replaceAll("ABC");
        System.out.println(replace);
        System.out.println("Equal:"+(stringWithSingleSlash.equals(replace)));
    }
}
```

This prints:

Matches:false

maybeABCno

Equal:false

- so it is not matching, but still replacing. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`matches` on returns true if the whole string matches - it doesn't match substrings.

So if `stringWithSingleSlash` were just `"\\"` instead of `"mabye\\no"`, `matches` would return true.

If the fact that `doubleSlash` matches a single backslash confuses you, the explanation is that `"\\\\"` is a string with two backslashes and the regex engine interprets two backslashes as one escaped backslash (because the backslash is an escape character in regexes as well as in string literals).

Answer (score 0):

The `matches()` function attempts to match the pattern against the entire string.
It seems like what you should use is to check if `.find()` returns `true`.

Take a look at the [Matcher javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html), here's an excerpt:

> Once created, a matcher can be used to
>   perform three different kinds of match
>   operations:
>
> - The matches method attempts to match
>     the entire input sequence against the
>     pattern.
> - The lookingAt method attempts to match
>     the input sequence, starting at the
>     beginning, against the pattern.
> - The find method scans the input
>     sequence looking for the next
>     subsequence that matches the pattern.
>
> Each of these methods returns a
>   boolean indicating success or failure.
>   More information about a successful
>   match can be obtained by querying the
>   state of the matcher.